# malformed bool query elasticsearch - Elasticsearch watcher

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Hi I have the below elastic search query using this in dev tools. I keep getting errors for my bool query but it seems correct looking at @timestamp field and trying to only retrieve one day worth of data.

```
    "input": {
      "search": {
        "request": {
          "indices": [
            "<iovation-*>"
          ],
          "body": {
            "size": 0,
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": {
                  "range": {
                    "@timestamp": {
                      "gte": "now-1d"
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
            "aggs": {
              "percentiles": {
                "percentiles": {
                  "field": "logstash.load.duration",
                  "percents": 95,
                  "keyed": false
                }
              },
              "dates": {
                "date_histogram": {
                  "field": "@timestamp",
                  "calendar_interval": "5m",
                  "min_doc_count": 1
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few errors in your query

1. Whenever aggregation is used along with the query part, then the structure is

   {
   "query": {},
   "aggs": {}
   }

You are missing one `}` at the end of the query part

2. [Calendar Intervals](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html#calendar_intervals) do not accept multiple quantities like 2d, 2m, etc.
3. If you have a fixed interval, then you can refer to the [`fixed_interval`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html#fixed_intervals) param

Modify your query as

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "range": {
          "@timestamp": {
            "gte": "now-1d"
          }
        }
      }
    }                               // note this
  },
  "aggs": {
    "percentiles": {
      "percentiles": {
        "field": "logstash.load.duration",
        "percents": 95,
        "keyed": false
      }
    },
    "dates": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "fixed_interval": "5m",           // note this
        "min_doc_count": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. Also thanks for pointing out the fixed_interval info! @ESCoder